# How to get the Final Redirected Url using PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I am trying to obtain the final url after multiple redirection. But i am able to get only the next immediate url after redirection and not the final one. So how do I get the final url. here is my code..

```
$url = 'http://withOutRedirectedURL.com/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //get header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); //do not include response body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //do not show in browser the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //follow any redirects
curl_exec($ch);
$new_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); //extract the url from the header response
curl_close($ch);

echo $new_url;
```

this code gives me the immediate next url i.e if I have a redirection like **url1 -> url2 -> url3**, I get url2 and not url3 from the above code. So how to get the final url?